# Excel VBA Sendkeys without delay

Tags: vba, excel, sendkeys

I'm trying to copy some cells from excel to another Windows application so fast as possible using Sendkeys. If I don't use "wait", Sendkeys fails. And if use it, Sendkeys run slowly and I need it in full speed, realtime if possible.
Anyone can help me?
Sorry for my English, I'm a brazilian student. 
Thank you

```
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10



Private Sub SingleClick()
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub DoubleClick()
  'Simulate a double click as a quick series of two clicks
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub

Private Sub RightClick()
  'Simulate a right click
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub


Sub Botão1_Clique()

'copy b2 and past in a specific area (another windows application)
Range("B2").Copy
SetCursorPos 765, 70
SingleClick
Application.SendKeys "^v"

Application.Wait (Now + 0.000007) ' It is the faster I can use but it's not enough

Range("B3").Copy
SetCursorPos 765, 80
SingleClick
Application.SendKeys "^v"

Application.Wait (Now + 0.000007)

Range("B4").Copy
SetCursorPos 765, 90
SingleClick
Application.SendKeys "^v"


End Sub
```

Comment: What other windows application are you trying to paste this in to? And does it support automation? If so, don't use `SendKeys`.

Comment: I'm trying to send a order to my homebroker (stock market). I need copy and paste the code stock, number of stocks and the price.

Comment: Try the answer below. Otherwise, Google turns up nothing when I search for "Homebroker" or "My Homebroker". Are you sure that is the name of the application? I was going to see if they provide any sort of API that you could reference...

Comment: Sorry! Homebroker is not a especific application. Is how we call the virtual place we use to trading. I can post the link but is in only in portuguese :( [link](https://www.investhb.com.br/Sistema/Operador-Mais.aspx) the application is called Operator+

Comment: Don't use SendKeys. They are highly unreliable. Use the FindWindow/SendMessage API

Answer (score 1):

While this likely isn't the best way to perform real-time trading, I think you can modify your SendKey statement to include the wait. I believe this `Application.SendKeys "^v", True` will force your code to pause for as long as it takes the command to execute, which might be faster than what you've coded.

Comment: Confirmed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: I tried it but didn't works.I know it is'nt the right way to trade. I love Excel and promisse me I can do this system. Just it. I'll not investing my family funds! :) I'll try again with ".True". Thank You so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SendKeys. They are highly unreliable. Use the [FindWindow](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindow.shtml)/[FindWindowEx](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/FindWindowEx.shtml)/[SendMessage](http://allapi.mentalis.org/apilist/SendMessage.shtml) API

See [THIS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/122d0a84-fbb7-4677-94ea-ca8b4693438e/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-open-excel-file-send-cell-contents-to-a-c-application-whenever-the-value) example where I have demonstrated on how to paste to a 3rd Party Application.

Based on that here is a simple example on how to paste from Excel to a 3rd party App.

Sample Code (**UNTESTED**)

```
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" _
(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" _
(ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, _
ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long

Private Const WM_PASTE As Long = &H302

Sub Botão1_Clique()
    Dim Ret
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change "BLAHBLAH" to the caption of the 3rd party app.
    Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "BLAHBLAH")

    If Ret <> 0 Then
        '~~> Change "BLAHBLAH" to the type of textbox
        '~~> Assuming that you want to paste to textbox else change it
        Ret = FindWindowEx(Ret, ByVal 0&, "BLAHBLAH", vbNullString)

        If Ret <> 0 Then
            '~~> Looping through only 5 cells
            '~~> Change as applicable
            For i = 1 To 5
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Copy

                '~~> Paste
                SendMessage Ret, WM_PASTE, 0, ByVal 0

                DoEvents
            Next i
        Else
            Debug.Print "TextBox in 3rd Party Application Not Found"
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "3rd party Application Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, David, Siddhart, I'll study about  FindWindow/SendMessage. I'm not a programmer but I love Excel VBA and now, love this site too!  :)

Comment: Ok I'm having the same SendKeys issues. I tried this code using "Untitled - Notepad", I got "3rd Party Application Not Found" (so textbox is not yet an issue). Any code that identifies 3rd party app window and GUI components, and how to find the value for WM_PASTE could be useful here.